# OpenCV: fatal error: openjpeg.h: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, build, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install the OpenCV on WSL2 by following the manuscript at
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

CMake was successfully done.But the `make -j{my_core}` occurs the error message

> fatal error: openjpeg.h: No such file or directory

How can I solve this problem?